# What docblock definition on this function will satisfy PHPLint?

Tags: php

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_validate().
 *
 * @param string $entity_type
 * @param object $entity
 * @param array $field
 * @param array $instance
 * @param array $langcode
 * @param array $items
 * @param array $errors
 *
 * @return void
 */
function field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    if (!empty($item['active'])) { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

The code above works well enough, but I would like to apply some static analysis on it. Enter [phplint](http://www.icosaedro.it/en-index.html), which doesn't like the `$item['active']` check. It says:

> Warning: can't check usage of `[' applied to a value of type mixed.

The warning makes sense, if I don't declare more details about my array, PHPLint won't know if the `[]`'s are applicable. My problem comes up when I read the [array documentation](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/manual.html?p=arrays) for PHPLint. I don't understand how I'm supposed to change the doc-block to properly describe the array.

Array structure with example data:

```
0 => array('active' => 1)
1 => array('active' => 0)
2 => array('active' => 1)
3 => array('active' => 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, did not noticed that, then:

@param int[int][string] $items

foreach($items as $k => $e){...}

here $k is int, $e is int[string].

In the general case, if

@param T[I1][I2][I3] $items

then

foreach($items as $k => $e){...}

yields $k of type I1 and $e of type T[I2][I3].

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked, and also helped me understand the logic. :)